# Parsing json issue: object.property is undefined

Tags: jquery, json

Here is the json returned by an ajax call:

```
{
    "StumbleUpon": 0,
    "Reddit": 0,
    "Facebook": {
        "commentsbox_count": 0,
        "click_count": 0,
        "total_count": 0,
        "comment_count": 0,
        "like_count": 0,
        "share_count": 0
    },
    "Delicious": 0,
    "GooglePlusOne": 1,
    "Buzz": 0,
    "Twitter": 1,
    "Diggs": 0,
    "Pinterest": 0,
    "LinkedIn": 1
}
```

I'm trying to process it in jquery but for some reason that i fail to understand, Facebook.total_count is undefined. I would expect otherwise since the console tells me the above json was received. Moreover, all others (data.Twitter, etc.) work. Here is my callback function where the error is produced. What am i doing wrong?

```
function(data){

                console.log(data);
//this line throws the error
                var fb = data.Facebook;
                var total = parseInt(data.Twitter + parseInt(fb.total_count) + data.GooglePlusOne + data.Pinterest + data.LinkedIn);
// rest of code.
}
```

See the code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MPCPx/).

Comment: Create a *pared down* replicating test case. Your live link is way too much to expect people to wade through. The code you've quoted, for instance, isn't in any `script` blocks on that page, so which of the 15 included `.js` files should people be looking in?

Comment: But fb.total_count work?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder done, sorry for that.

Comment: @pixeline: Your fiddle doesn't give any error that I can see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fundamentally, [that code works](http://jsbin.com/esogog/2) -- provided that `data` has already been deserialized. If it hasn't, either...

...add `dataType: "JSON"` to the `ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    dataType: "JSON",
    // ...
});
```

...or use `$.parseJSON` on the result.

```
function(data) {
    if (typeof data === "string") {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

Note: You don't need to use `parseInt` on those numbers, they're already numbers in the JSON and will be deserialized correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your receieving the JSON as a string but nor parsing it into an actual object. Theres too much on the page to really sift through and tell you accuratly but this seems to be the issue. try [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)